# Can a single ResultSet variable of Execute SQL Task hold multiple datasets in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I have a situation where i have to use two execute sql tasks which yields  the result and stored in an result set varibale rsProgress. can I use the same result set variable in two for each loop containers.

Example:

EST 1 contains query : select eid, ename from emp where eid=2 the result of this stored in user::rsprogress variable.

EST2 contains query: select eid, ename,designation from emp its result can also ne stored in the same user variable user:rsprogress.

later I want to use this variable user::rsprogress to be used in for each loop containers. is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunatelly you cant.

I suggest you to make a copy of your record set before the first use